# Is there any way to put a thermometer chart inside of the category name on another chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm using Excel 2016 and have a bar chart showing Manhours/Actual Hour. I want to make the horizontal category labels have a separate bar chart within them, showing time spent out of time possible (Manhours compared to total possible Manhours). I created a bar chart showing the Manhours spent with the max axis showing Manhours possible. However, I don't know of any way to make this chart part of the axis label of my other chart. I want it to look like this.

[image: I want it to look like this.]

Does anyone know of any way to do this?

Sorry if the picture is bad, I made it in paint with random numbers.

Comment: no, there is no way for that, apart from preparing separately and dragging manually.

Comment: That's what I thought. I figured I might as well ask. Thanks.